# Find resource for CultureInfo

Tags: c#, .net, localization, resources

I need to determine whether there is a resource file for the given CultureInfo or not.

Is there an easy way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ResourceSet ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(
    CultureInfo culture,
    bool createIfNotExists,
    bool tryParents )`

Example:

```
ResourceManager resman = new ResourceManager();
CultureInfo culinfo = new CultureInfo( "RU-ru" );
if( resman.GetResourceSet( culinfo, false, false ) == null )
{
    Console.WriteLine( "Resource file for culture \"RU-ru\" does not exist." );
}
```

Comment: I've tried the code you provieded but it does not work. Here is some more information about my resource files:

I have two resource files defined
Resources.resx (+ .Designer.cs)
Resources.de.resx

I use the ResourceManager provided by the Resource-Class

resman.GetResourceSet(new CultureInfo("de-DE"), false, false) return null altough I have defined a resource for geman language.

Taking a look at the ResourceManager instance showed, that there are three ResourceSets defined:
- {en}
- {}
- {en-US}

But there is no ResourceSet for 'de-DE' defined.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hmm, please check that you resource file is compiled into resource dll?